# Should 1-time use data like verification code to be stored in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

When a user registers an account, I issue a verification code that is later used to verify the account. Once verified, the account is marked `verified=1` and the verification code erased. Should such data like the verification code be placed in a separate table?

Comment: Why would you think that it might be better to place it in a separate table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is of course much better to store temporary data separate from nontemporary. There is no need to store that key in the account table. Have some tblVerificationCodes with FKs to the account table, timestamps etc etc and delete (or archieve if needed) data from this table when its possible. This is very good style.

Answer (score 2):

if you plan to store some other data, like verificationDate, ipAddress, etc. you should use a different table for verification information. But if you do not plan to use any data, but the "verified" column, about the verification, only one column can be stored in the same table,

Comment: Is it common practice to store that additional data?

Comment: You might want to expire the verification code if it is not used after a certain time, so you might want to store a timestamp.

Comment: @zmol: I usually use additional information, that can help me on making some decisions. And, in my opinion, you should use some extra information which you think that will help you to make some decisions.